# Establish a company (UG) while being employed

Tags: germany, taxes, employment, company

I have a permanent residency (Niederlassungserlaubnis) in Germany and I’m employed full time. I want to create a company (UG) so I can upload my apps in Apple app store and benefits from tax advantages and separate my personal finance from the business (mobile apps) I have some questions:

1. After creating the company, do I have to change tax class to 6 (second job). Even though the company will not earn any income in the first year !
2. can I open the UG with just 1 person (me) ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you going to only establish a company (then legally this is nothing different from buying stocks / investment), or you will also work for it? In the second case, one needs to double-check a contract with the main job, which could require to apply for a permission from employer for working in parallel for own company.

Answering your questions:

1. If one does not work and does not get salary, no tax class change is usually needed. Tax classes are anyhow not so important, since they almost never affect the amount of taxes one pays.
2. Yes. In this case, however, checking the contract with main job is also recommended, cause if one has UG with just one person, it will be impossible to justify that you do not work for it.

P.S. I'm neither a lawyer, nor a tax consultant. This is a sharing of my opinion on generic case and not a professional advice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will not get salary from my UG. I will keep just getting one salary from my current full time job.

Comment: Still checking the contract with main job is recommended, especially if you have UG with just one person (it will be impossible to justify that you do not work for it).

Comment: Thank you for the information. But regarding the tax class no need yo change it since I will be employed in my current company. But own another company without receiving a salary. Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you actually do paid work for that company, then you (the employee) would have to tell yourself (the company) that this is a second job, and the company would have to deduct taxes from your salary at a very high rate, to make sure you are not underpaying. At the end of the tax year, you make your income tax declaration, fill in what money you made from both jobs, and how much you paid in taxes in each job, and the correct tax will be calculated. Most likely you will vastly overpay during the year and get a huge refund.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will not get salary from my UG the income will be saved in a business account of the UG. It will be mainly passive income from Apple app store app subscriptions. I will just do some maintenance in weekends nothing more.  I will keep just getting one salary from my current full time job.